# Incorrect Remote Address when deployed

Tags: node.js, deployment, nginx, meteor, passenger

I deployed my application in my private server and I'm using nginx with Phusion Passenger.

This simple code:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('playground/remoteAddress', {
        where: 'server',
        action: function () {
            var remoteAddress = this.request.connection.remoteAddress;
            this.response.end(remoteAddress);
        }
    })
});
```

Always returns 127.0.0.1

I'm assuming that there's some component in middle that is making the request. The server and the meteor application are running in the same machine.

I deploy this code to meteor free hosting: http://remote-ip.meteor.com and it returns `10.37.38.22` which is obviously wrong.

I can't validate external IP's calling some services, example: Payments callback